# Error Missing ID - layout-w900dp @+id/item_list: - layout en Android 4.x, Como solucinar la perdida del Id en layouts versionados?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, adb, avd

```
Configurations for item_list.xml must agree on the root element's ID.

Missing ID:
 - layout-w900dp

@+id/item_list:
 - layout
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estimad@s

Compañeros como pueden apreciar, este error me salta al instante de compilar el emulador, he investigado una posible solucion; sin embargo, al momento de establecer el mismo 'ID' en el archivo item_list.xml, que son los mismo archivos pero con diferentes densidades, no surte ningun efecto.
No logro entener el motivo de el mismo, ya que segun los foros en ingles mencionan que solo se debe realizar eso.

Por favor, su amable ayuda con una posible solucion o alternativa.

File: layout\item_list.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/item_list"
        android:name="com.undroider.dinnermenus.ItemListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_content" />
```

File: layout-w900dp\item_list.xml

```
 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle"
        tools:context=".ItemListActivity">
    
        <!--
        This layout is a two-pane layout for the Items master/detail flow.
        -->
    
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/item_list"
            android:name="com.undroider.dinnermenus.ItemListFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/item_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
            tools:context="com.undroider.dinnermenus.ItemListActivity"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_content" />
    
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

La verdad, no se si el anidanmiento en el RecyclerView, tenga alguna influencia en dicho erro, por favor su gentil ayuda en este grave inconventiente.

Adicionalmente estoy utilizando 'ViewBinding' para la vinculacion de vistas.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El directorio donde se debe encontrar el archivo  `item_list.xml` debe ser `layout-w900dp\` no `w900dp\`

El error indica que una versión de tu layout en alguno de los directorios tiene un id diferente, asegura que los layouts tengan el mismo id!.

Actualización:

Otra causa del mensaje que indica:

> Configurations for item_list.xml must agree on the root element's ID.

Es que en la raíz alguno de los archivos no tiene el mismo contenedor.

Al revisar ambos layouts en los directorios `/layout` y `/layout-w900dp` el problema se debe a que `/layout/item_list.xml` solo contiene un `RecyclerView` a diferencia de el archivo  `/layout-w900dp/item_list.xml` que contiene un contenedor (`LinearLayout`) y dentro un `RecyclerView` y un `FrameLayout`.

La solución es agregar en la raíz del archivo `/layout/item_list.xml` un contenedor, por ejemplo agregando un `LinearLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:showDividers="middle"
    tools:context=".ItemListActivity">

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/item_list"
    android:name="com.undroider.dinnermenus.ItemListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".ItemListActivity"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_list_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `@Jorgesys`, estimado compañero gracias por tu gentil respueta. Sin embargo, efectivamente en ese directorio se encuentra el archivo  `item_list.xml`, en `layout-w900dp`, debido a que lo abrevie, me disculpo por ello. Si he revisado muchas veces pro no logro encontra que ìd` esta diferente. Sera que es por el anidamiento en el `item_list.xml` de 900dp?, pro como pueden aprecier tienen el mismo `id`, x lo que no comprendo a cabalidad por que surge el mismo error.

Comment: Busca todos los item_list.xml , si todos estan correctos limpia tu proyecto y genera nuevamente tu aplicaciòn.

Comment: Si, efectivamente eso itente pro ahora igualmente estuve probando realizar `clean project` y  `rebuild project`, y tampoco me funciono, por lo que intento ahora crear un nuevo projecto y encontrar algun error, con todo tengo una duda, estimado `@JorgeSys`, sera que al usar el `viewBinding` se me desconfiguaria la referencias de `Ids`, ya que no lo estaba implementando en el projecto de tipo `Master/Detail flow`, y sin ello estaba funcionando correctamente. Si conoces algo muchas gracias x tu ayuda, esa intriga todavia no la puedo descartar.
Saludos

Comment: Ya revise el error que tienes nuevamente, revisa mi actualización por favor, saludos.

Comment: `@JorgeSys`, muy agradecido en verdad, no pude encontrar la razon, para este error, aunque no logro entenderlo por completo, ya que el `Master/flow`, estaba funcionando correctamente y en el momento de añadir mas funciones se crasheo. Te agradezco mucho, x tu ayuda con esto.

Comment: Como comento en mi actualización en el layout /layout/item_list.xml agrega un contenedor a el RecyclerView con eso se soluciona el problema.! :D